# xrdp disconnects immediately after connection from Windows10 to Ubuntu only after restarting service

Tags: xorg, xrdp

Currently I am able to connect to my remote server with windows remote desktop. But, if I run `sudo systemclt restart xrdp`, then xrdp disconnects after correct login information is entered in initial login screen. Restarting the server fixes this issue. I still encounter this issue even if I don't change any xrdp settings be for the restart. My question is, why does it break after restarting and what can I do to prevent it.

Note: Since this a server that is used frequently, I am hesitant to reinstall xrdp since it works for the most part.

**xrdp.ini**

```
[Globals]
; xrdp.ini file version number
ini_version=1

; fork a new process for each incoming connection
fork=true
; tcp port to listen
port=3389
; 'port' above should be connected to with vsock instead of tcp
use_vsock=false
; regulate if the listening socket use socket option tcp_nodelay
; no buffering will be performed in the TCP stack
tcp_nodelay=true
; regulate if the listening socket use socket option keepalive
; if the network connection disappear without close messages the connection will be closed
tcp_keepalive=true
#tcp_send_buffer_bytes=32768
#tcp_recv_buffer_bytes=32768

; security layer can be 'tls', 'rdp' or 'negotiate'
; for client compatible layer
security_layer=negotiate
; minimum security level allowed for client
; can be 'none', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'fips'
crypt_level=high
; X.509 certificate and private key
; openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
certificate=
key_file=
; set SSL protocols
; can be comma separated list of 'SSLv3', 'TLSv1', 'TLSv1.1', 'TLSv1.2'
ssl_protocols=TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2
; set TLS cipher suites
#tls_ciphers=HIGH

; Section name to use for automatic login if the client sends username
; and password. If empty, the domain name sent by the client is used.
; If empty and no domain name is given, the first suitable section in
; this file will be used.
autorun=

allow_channels=true
allow_multimon=true
bitmap_cache=true
bitmap_compression=true
bulk_compression=true
#hidelogwindow=true
max_bpp=32
new_cursors=true
; fastpath - can be 'input', 'output', 'both', 'none'
use_fastpath=both
; when true, userid/password *must* be passed on cmd line
#require_credentials=true
; You can set the PAM error text in a gateway setup (MAX 256 chars)
#pamerrortxt=change your password according to policy at http://url

;
; colors used by windows in RGB format
;
blue=009cb5
grey=dedede
#black=000000
#dark_grey=808080
#blue=08246b
#dark_blue=08246b
#white=ffffff
#red=ff0000
#green=00ff00
#background=626c72

;
; configure login screen
;

; Login Screen Window Title
#ls_title=My Login Title

; top level window background color in RGB format
ls_top_window_bg_color=009cb5

; width and height of login screen
ls_width=350
ls_height=430

; login screen background color in RGB format
ls_bg_color=dedede

; optional background image filename (bmp format).
#ls_background_image=

; logo
; full path to bmp-file or file in shared folder
ls_logo_filename=
ls_logo_x_pos=55
ls_logo_y_pos=50

; for positioning labels such as username, password etc
ls_label_x_pos=30
ls_label_width=60

; for positioning text and combo boxes next to above labels
ls_input_x_pos=110
ls_input_width=210

; y pos for first label and combo box
ls_input_y_pos=220

; OK button
ls_btn_ok_x_pos=142
ls_btn_ok_y_pos=370
ls_btn_ok_width=85
ls_btn_ok_height=30

; Cancel button
ls_btn_cancel_x_pos=237
ls_btn_cancel_y_pos=370
ls_btn_cancel_width=85
ls_btn_cancel_height=30

[Logging]
LogFile=xrdp.log
LogLevel=DEBUG
EnableSyslog=true
SyslogLevel=DEBUG
; LogLevel and SysLogLevel could by any of: core, error, warning, info or debug

[Channels]
; Channel names not listed here will be blocked by XRDP.
; You can block any channel by setting its value to false.
; IMPORTANT! All channels are not supported in all use
; cases even if you set all values to true.
; You can override these settings on each session type
; These settings are only used if allow_channels=true
rdpdr=true
rdpsnd=true
drdynvc=true
cliprdr=true
rail=true
xrdpvr=true
tcutils=true

; for debugging xrdp, in section xrdp1, change port=-1 to this:
#port=/tmp/.xrdp/xrdp_display_10

; for debugging xrdp, add following line to section xrdp1
#chansrvport=/tmp/.xrdp/xrdp_chansrv_socket_7210


;
; Session types
;

; Some session types such as Xorg, X11rdp and Xvnc start a display server.
; Startup command-line parameters for the display server are configured
; in sesman.ini. See and configure also sesman.ini.
[Xorg]
name=Xorg
lib=libxup.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
code=20

[X11rdp]
name=X11rdp
lib=libxup.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
xserverbpp=24
code=10

[Xvnc]
name=Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
#xserverbpp=24
#delay_ms=2000

[console]
name=console
lib=libvnc.so
ip=127.0.0.1
port=5900
username=na
password=ask
#delay_ms=2000

[vnc-any]
name=vnc-any
lib=libvnc.so
ip=ask
port=ask5900
username=na
password=ask
#pamusername=asksame
#pampassword=asksame
#pamsessionmng=127.0.0.1
#delay_ms=2000

[sesman-any]
name=sesman-any
lib=libvnc.so
ip=ask
port=-1
username=ask
password=ask
#delay_ms=2000

[neutrinordp-any]
name=neutrinordp-any
lib=libxrdpneutrinordp.so
ip=ask
port=ask3389
username=ask
password=ask

; You can override the common channel settings for each session type
#channel.rdpdr=true
#channel.rdpsnd=true
#channel.drdynvc=true
#channel.cliprdr=true
#channel.rail=true
#channel.xrdpvr=true
```

**/etc/X11/xrdp/xorg.conf**

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "X11 Server"
    Screen "Screen (xrdpdev)"
    InputDevice "xrdpMouse" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice "xrdpKeyboard" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "DontVTSwitch" "on"
    Option "AutoAddDevices" "off"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load "dbe"
    Load "ddc"
    Load "extmod"
    Load "glx"
    Load "int10"
    Load "record"
    Load "vbe"
    Load "xorgxrdp"
    Load "fb"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier "xrdpKeyboard"
    Driver "xrdpkeyb"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier "xrdpMouse"
    Driver "xrdpmouse"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Monitor"
    Option "DPMS"
    HorizSync 30-80
    VertRefresh 60-75
    ModeLine "1920x1080" 138.500 1920 1968 2000 2080 1080 1083 1088 1111 +hsync -vsync
    ModeLine "1280x720" 74.25 1280 1720 1760 1980 720 725 730 750 +HSync +VSync
    Modeline "1368x768" 72.25 1368 1416 1448 1528 768 771 781 790 +hsync -vsync
    Modeline "1600x900" 119.00 1600 1696 1864 2128 900 901 904 932 -hsync +vsync
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Video Card (xrdpdev)"
    Driver "xrdpdev"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen (xrdpdev)"
    Device "Video Card (xrdpdev)"
    Monitor "Monitor"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth 24
        Modes "640x480" "800x600" "1024x768" "1280x720" "1280x1024" "1600x900" "1920x1080"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

**/etc/X11/xorg.conf**

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 440.31

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

After pressing ok on this scree is where it disconnects.
[image: Login Screen]

Server OS: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS x86_64